# factory_girl causing RSpec spec to fail after Rails 4 upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, factory-bot

I just upgraded my app to Rails 4 and several of my RSpec specs now fail, all in the same way.

```
SQL (82.3ms)  INSERT INTO "profiles" ("career_goal", "created_at", "email", "encrypted_password", "first_name", "gpa", "grad_year", "hidden", "keywords", "kind", "last_name", "major_names", "middle_name", "minor_names", "phone", "id", "research_interest", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["career_goal", ["Illum et sunt.", "Illo sapiente nesciunt reiciendis nulla fugit est autem."]], ["created_at", Sat, 21 Jun 2014 15:12:40 PDT -07:00], ["email", "madonna@huels.name"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$10$y1zijhGouDy1OT4qHGnXR./FvXP9T7DHHvu4BofAt5ZBJrqjFisty"], ["first_name", "Jayde"], ["gpa", #<BigDecimal:e684850,'0.25E1',18(36)>], ["grad_year", 2013], ["hidden", false], ["keywords", "Daisha Ea placeat debitis repellendus autem ad voluptas. Illum et sunt. Illo sapiente nesciunt reiciendis nulla fugit est autem.   "], ["kind", "student"], ["last_name", "Reilly"], ["major_names", "Anthropology"], ["middle_name", "Daisha"], ["minor_names", "Sociology"], ["phone", "724-953-4023 x4372"], ["id", "01234567"], ["research_interest", "Ea placeat debitis repellendus autem ad voluptas."], ["updated_at", Sat, 21 Jun 2014 15:12:40 PDT -07:00]]

TypeError: can't cast Array to text: INSERT INTO "profiles" ("career_goal", "created_at", "email", "encrypted_password", "first_name", "gpa", "grad_year", "hidden", "keywords", "kind", "last_name", "major_names", "middle_name", "minor_names", "phone", "id", "research_interest", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

It looks like the SQL call is somehow malformed now in the for of `INSERT INTO "profiles" ("fields", etc) VALUES (?,?,?)` Any insight as to why the VALUES part is all ?s would be appreciated. I checked my define for :profile and it doesn't seem to be a Faker issue as I had read elsewhere. (I have `Faker::Lorem.words(4).join('-')` which doesn't give an array or anything. Is this an Active Record problem? Is there anywhere else I should be looking for errors or things that need reconfiguring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question marks aren't a problem; they're placeholders for the values.

This part of your array of values

```
["career_goal", ["Illum et sunt.", "Illo sapiente nesciunt reiciendis nulla fugit est autem."]]
```

indicates that `career_goal` is set to an array. Change it to a single string (with `join` or by rewriting it, whatever).